# Как поменять значения экземпляров класса друг с другом C#

Tags: c#

Использую метод для замены значений экземпляров класса друг с другом вот так

```
void Change(ref Array_member V1, ref Array_member V2) 
        {
            Array_member V;
            V = V1;
            V1 = V2;
            V2 = V;             
        }
```

Но это работает не так как я хочу. Я сам толком разобраться не могу, но кажется что значения индексатора меняются, а значения полей и свойств нет.
Вот код класса

```
 class Array_member
    {
        internal int Index { get; set; }
        internal int Value { get; set; }
        internal int GrHeigth { get; set; }
        internal int x { get; set; }       
        static internal int GrWidth, YCoef;
        internal SolidBrush brush;
        
        internal static Array_member[] members = new Array_member[10];
        public Array_member this[int index]
        {
            get {                
                return members[index]; 
            }
            set { members[index] = value; }
        }

        public static Bitmap bmap = new Bitmap(800,500);
        public static Graphics display = Graphics.FromImage(bmap);
        internal void DrawMember()
        {            
            GrHeigth = YCoef * Value;
            display.FillRectangle(brush, x, GrHeigth, GrWidth, 500);
        }

        public static bool operator <(Array_member a1, Array_member a2)
        {
            return a1.Value < a2.Value;
        }

        public static bool operator >(Array_member a1, Array_member a2)
        {
            return a1.Value > a2.Value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: А где вызов этого `Change`? На него бы ещё посмотреть.

Comment: Зачем вообще менять поля, если это только лишняя работа?

Comment: for (int i = 1; i < Array_member.members.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (Array_member.members[i] < Array_member.members[i - 1])
                    {                      

                        Change(ref Array_member.members[i], ref Array_member.members[i - 1]);                                 
                    }                    
                }

Comment: @Syponchik опять же, зачем менять поля?

Comment: @Syponchik `for (int i = 1; ...`: ну-ну) в C# массивы по стандарту индексируются с `0`

Comment: @Syponchik В методе `Change` вы меняете ссылки, а не поля. Если бы это был не `class`, а `struct`, то тогда менялись бы значения полей.

Comment: @return Переделал класс в структуру - ничего не изменилось. 
Мне необходимо поменять местами экземпляры класса в массиве, чтобы поменялось значение свойства x, которое зависит от индекса экземпляра класса в массиве.

Comment: @Syponchik просто нужно было ещё свапнуть индекс...

Comment: Не нужно удалять вопрос после того как вам дали ответ. Ответы не только для вас, но и для будущих посетителей сайта. Если вы считаете, что ответ вам помог, вы можете отметить его галкой слева от ответа (см. [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers))

Answer (score 4):

```
public static void Swap<T>(ref T a, ref T b)
{
    var tmp = a;
    a = b;
    b = tmp;
}
```

```
for (int i = 1; i < Array_member.members.Length; i++)
{
    if (Array_member.members[i] < Array_member.members[i - 1])
    {
        Swap(ref Array_member.members[i].Index, ref Array_member.members[i - 1]);
        Swap(ref Array_member.members[i], ref Array_member.members[i - 1]);
    }
}
```